# Adding custom preferences to System Settings

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

Can I add custom PreferenceActivity to system settings (Settings.apk)? I have several applications, settings which I would like to combine in one place.

Answer (score 1):

There is no external framework to accomplish this for developers in the SDK.  The only way to create custom behavior in a system application like Settings is to modify the application sources directly and distribute the modified app with a custom ROM.

HTH

Comment: The `ContentProvider` framework is provided to you instead as a way that you can have multiple applications which share a common set of data (in this case, preferences).